# Hadoop`s best version for spark 2.4

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am a beginner for BIG DATA(spark), Nowadays, I have installed spark2.4, So I want to know which best version should be chosen. Because I want to avoid conflict, which so bad.

Comment: ???  just a beginner,if you know,please tell you,thank you.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Please read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Just use the Hadoop included with Spark and you won't have issues

Answer (score 2):

Apache hadoop 2.7.7 is a stable release to be used. However, I've setup Apache hadoop 3.1.1 and running Spark 2.4 with it and have not seen any issues.

If you are doing it for practice better use 3.1.1 version and for production I  would recommend using a more stable release.

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Yes. happy to help!!